# Why the select method is not working in the category field?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

My Code:

```
public class asdadsd {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://talentrack.in");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/span")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userlogin']/div/div[4]/a[1]")));

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='userlogin']/div/div[4]/a[1]")).click();


    WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='name']"));
    name.sendKeys("anyname");

    //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
      //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("select[id='cat_id'][name='cat_id']")));

    Thread.sleep(5000L);

    //WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[id='cat_id'][name='cat_id']"));

    WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cat_id"));

    Select a =new Select(category);

    a.selectByValue("5");
}

}
```

What is wrong with category drop-down ? I'm able to fill values in other drop-downs. Please Help me in getting rid of this.

Error:
Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds

I applied wait to, still it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

@Kishan,

In your code WebDriver unable to select the dropdown because it found two matching element with your css selector. PFA the screenshot. [image: CSS selector showing two nodes]So if you want to use css selector then you can use:

**#cat_id[class='input-control modal-tab-selection placeholder-color']** instead of **#cat_id**.

```
WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#cat_id[class='input-control modal-tab-selection placeholder-color']"));

Select a =new Select(category);

a.selectByValue("5");
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Not working. Let me try to customize the path so that it is unique. Thank you for telling me root cause. @Vaibhav

Answer (score 0):

```
    WebElement category = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cat_id'][@data-message='required']"));
    Select a =new Select(category);
    a.selectByValue("4");
```

Finally i got it..

This was the xpath which helped me to uniquely identify the dropdown. Thanks Vaibhav for your help. Never trust xpath, better create your own. ha ha..
Happy Learning. :-)